# Powershell - What does "{0:N0}" mean?

Tags: .net, powershell

(I'm not English. Hope you understand.)

Hi, I somewhere saw this:

```
PS > "{0:N0}" -f 10000000000
10,000,000,000
```

What does `"{0:N0}"` do?

Thanks for answers.

-Andrew

Comment: `-f` is the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f). Per the docs, this uses `String.Format`, which takes a [composite format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string). `N0` specifically is a [numeric format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#numeric-format-specifier-n).

Comment: To add to Jeroen's spot-on comment above: `N` = numeric speficier, `0` = "with 0 decimal places"